# Write jump to memory

Tags: c++, detours

I'm trying to write a jump to memory, and I can't seem to find anywhere which can explain me how it works.

```
typedef UINT(WINAPI* tResetWriteWatch)(LPVOID lpBaseAddress, SIZE_T dwRegionSize);

UINT WINAPI ResetWriteWatchHook(LPVOID lpBaseAddress, SIZE_T dwRegionSize){
    printf("Function called\n");
    return 0;
}

void main(){
    DWORD64 hookAddr = (DWORD64)&ResetWriteWatch;
    WriteJump(hookAddr, ResetWriteWatchHook/*Let's say it's 0x7FE12345678*/);//Writes E9 XX XX XX XX to memory
}
```

My main issue is that I don't understand: how do I convert asm JMP 0x7FE12345678 to E9 XX XX XX XX so I can write it at hookAddr.

Process is 64 bits.

Comment: What are you trying to do here that can't be done by conventional C++? Is this related to the Detours angle?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done using conventional C++, but I don't know much of windows api functions, so this seemed the best way to do it. (ResetWriteWatch is in kernel32.dll)

Answer (score 2):

This is how it's commonly done on a 32bit program (not sure how much is different on 64 bit), but this should give you an idea on where to go. This is specific to windows because of `VirtualProtect`, but you can use `mprotect` if you are on linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void foo() {
    printf("Foo!");
}

void my_foo() {
    printf("My foo!");
}

int setJMP(void *from, void *to) {
    DWORD protection;
    if (!VirtualProtect(from, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &protection)) { // We must be able to write to it (don't necessarily need execute and read)
        return 0;
    }

    *(char *)from = 0xE9; // jmp opcode
    *(int *)(from + 1) = (int)(to - from - 5); // relative addr

    return VirtualProtect(from, 5, protection, &protection); // Restore original protection
}

int main() {
    setJMP(foo, my_foo);
    foo(); // outputs "My foo!"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want o inject **JMP** on any other process's Memory then this logic won't work you have to use **WriteProcessMemory** method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an assembler to generate the correct bytes. Simply create the following file and run it through NASM:

```
BITS 64
JUMP 0x7fe1234
```

The result is:

`2f e9 fe 12 00 07` (due to the LE byte order). This is a relative jump, so it will be hard to generate from high level code. You might want to use the opcode `EA` instead, which performs an absolute jump. Then you can simply use the absolute address of the location to which you want to jump.

Comment: I know that xx are placeholders, I put them there trying to say that I don't know what are the proper bytes that goes there. How do you get the "07 FE 12 34" part ?

Comment: That's the address being jumped to; it's where program execution needs to go.

Comment: I'll edit it in a sec. The real addresses are more than 4 bytes long

Comment: I re-wrote the answer to give you a better process to follow.

Comment: How would I get that result using c++ though, since the address changes each time I reboot the program ?

Comment: Oh, I see; you want to generate it. Give me a sec.

Comment: OK, I've added a little more info. Unfortunately I'm at the limit of my knowledge here; sorry.

Comment: it's not jump just jmp